# php response getting very slow (with mysql)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I'm developing a dashboard, it've a notifications also so i planned for a live notifications with ajax,php,mysql.i've made it possible but the mysqli(from php) reads is slow for fetch results from database,below is my code

this is my javascript code on index.php:

```
comres = {
                            connect: function() {

                                    return $.ajax({
                                            url: 'read_notification.php',
                                            type: 'POST',

                                            success: function(evt, request) {
                                                     alert(evt);

                                            },
                                            complete: function() {

                                                    comres.connect();
                                            }
                                    });
                            }

                    }

                    $(document).ready(function() {

                            comres.connect();
                    });
```

below is my read_notification.php

```
<?php




 require_once("db.php");



 $query=mysqli_query($db,"select * from notifications");

while(mysqli_num_rows($query) < 1)
{
}

$query1 = mysqli_query($db,"select * from notifications");

 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1);

 $id=$row['id'];
  $notification=$row['notification'];



 echo "you have a notification ".$notification

mysqli_query($db,"delete from ticket.handover_response where id='$id'");


 ?>
```

below is working flow

1. javascript calls the `read_notification.php` when loads the `index.php`
2. read_notification.php fire the query to database with while loop,while loop continuous still the database have any one entry on notification table
3. when the database table have a entry the while loop get fails and the response back to the index.php

here no problem is in working flow but i've a delay on after have a record on database(php is not reading suddenly from database,it's working after few more seconds), please suggest the reason or solution for this, thanks

Comment: learn code formatting as well as Stack Overflow markdown

Comment: have you installed any debugger like xdebug ?

Comment: Why do you call `comres.connect()` again in `complete`? Try getting rid of that and see if that works.

Comment: instead of using while loop at php why not use jquery timer and send ajax request to fetch notifaction time to time.

Comment: if i set ajax with time interval for get the nofication,it sends request frequently, but in current mode the current request is wait still the response is came, after that it reconnect to for next response

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function(){
//set up an ajax request every 2 sec
   comres.connect();
},2000);
});
```

In your php simply display new notification based on some flag variable.that is if user click the notification set the flag to one (dont show again)otherwise mark it as zero.